# WatchKit: Passing data from third controller to the initial controller

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a Watch app that has three controllers. The main controller, another one with a table view and the last one which is a settings controller. In the settings controller I have a switch. When it's value is changed, the value is stored to a bool variable. I want to send this variable's value to the first controller, so that when I swipe back to the first controller the value will be sent there. Is it possible? How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to use `contextForSegueWithIdentifier`. You have to return data from this method, and access that data within your target class, in your case "first controller".

You can implement it like this:

```
// In settings controller

override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {

    return self.currentValue

// In first controller
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    if let value: String = context as? String {
        print(value)

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just researched this problem and I learned that someone also has an if statement with segueIdentifier == "controller name". Do I need to put it there?

Comment: So how it recognises that it is supposed to pass this information to the first controller and not the second one, which is between them (the first and the third) in the Storyboard file?

Comment: You have to add a segueIdentifier, which is identifier for segue you will make between your first and settings controller so it will go to that controller.